# How to replace bookmarks in ".docx", using POI without loosing format?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to replace bookmark with values.

```
private FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\test.docx"));
private XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
List<XWPFParagraph> paraList = this.document.getParagraphs();

private final void procParaList(List<XWPFParagraph> paraList, String bookmarkName, String bookmarkValue) {
    Iterator<XWPFParagraph> paraIter = null;
    XWPFParagraph para = null;
    List<CTBookmark> bookmarkList = null;
    Iterator<CTBookmark> bookmarkIter = null;
    CTBookmark bookmark = null;
    XWPFRun run = null;
    Node nextNode = null;

    paraIter = paraList.iterator();
    while (paraIter.hasNext()) {
        para = paraIter.next();
        bookmarkList = para.getCTP().getBookmarkStartList();
        bookmarkIter = bookmarkList.iterator();

        while (bookmarkIter.hasNext()) {
            bookmark = bookmarkIter.next();
            if (bookmark.getName().equals(bookmarkName)) {
                run = para.createRun();
                run.setText(bookmarkValue);
                nextNode = bookmark.getDomNode().getNextSibling();
                while (!(nextNode.getNodeName().contains("bookmarkEnd"))) {
                    para.getCTP().getDomNode().removeChild(nextNode);
                    nextNode = bookmark.getDomNode().getNextSibling();
                }
                para.getCTP().getDomNode().insertBefore(run.getCTR().getDomNode(), nextNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to replace bookmark to value but it is not keeping the same format(font family, font size, color etc) as bookmark text have.

Can anyone please provide some advice.

Comment: seems you need to extract the styling information from existing para and apply the same to the replacement para you create, try using getStyle and setStyle methods provided by XWPFParagraph class

Comment: I found formatting option like run.setFontFamily( runExisting.getFontFamily());, But not able to find, how to pick existing bookmark format.

Answer (score 0):

As Discussed earlier , i believe this is your exact use case , official archive link 
[help](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201206.mbox/%3C1340981358470-5710333.post@n5.nabble.com%3E)  Please focus on the use of **Node styleNode** to copy the style information.

```
    /**
     * Replace the text - if any - contained between the bookmarkStart and
it's
     * matching bookmarkEnd tag with the text specified. The technique used
will
     * resemble that employed when inserting text after the bookmark. In
short,
     * the code will iterate along the nodes until it encounters a matching
     * bookmarkEnd tag. Each node encountered will be deleted unless it is
the
     * final node before the bookmarkEnd tag is encountered and it is a
     * character run. If this is the case, then it can simply be updated to
     * contain the text the users wishes to see inserted into the document.
If
     * the last node is not a character run, then it will be deleted, a new
run
     * will be created and inserted into the paragraph between the
bookmarkStart
     * and bookmarkEnd tags.
     *
     * @param run An instance of the XWPFRun class that encapsulates the
text
     * that is to be inserted into the document following the bookmark.
     */
    private void replaceBookmark(XWPFRun run) {
        Node nextNode = null;
        Node styleNode = null;
        Node lastRunNode = null;
        Node toDelete = null;
        NodeList childNodes = null;
        Stack<Node> nodeStack = null;
        boolean textNodeFound = false;
        boolean foundNested = true;
        int bookmarkStartID = 0;
        int bookmarkEndID = -1;
        int numChildNodes = 0;

        nodeStack = new Stack<Node>();
        bookmarkStartID = this._ctBookmark.getId().intValue();
        nextNode = this._ctBookmark.getDomNode();
        nodeStack.push(nextNode);

        // Loop through the nodes looking for a matching bookmarkEnd tag
        while (bookmarkStartID != bookmarkEndID) {
            nextNode = nextNode.getNextSibling();
            nodeStack.push(nextNode);

            // If an end tag is found, does it match the start tag? If so,
end
            // the while loop.
            if (nextNode.getNodeName().contains(Bookmark.BOOKMARK_END_TAG))
{
                try {
                    bookmarkEndID = Integer.parseInt(
                            nextNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem(
                            Bookmark.BOOKMARK_ID_ATTR_NAME).getNodeValue());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    bookmarkEndID = bookmarkStartID;
                }
            }
            //else {
                // Place a reference to the node on the nodeStack
            //    nodeStack.push(nextNode);
            //}
        }

        // If the stack of nodes found between the bookmark tags is not
empty
        // then they have to be removed.
        if (!nodeStack.isEmpty()) {

            // Check the node at the top of the stack. If it is a run, get
it's
            // style - if any - and apply to the run that will be replacing
it.
            //lastRunNode = nodeStack.pop();
            lastRunNode = nodeStack.peek();
            if ((lastRunNode.getNodeName().equals(Bookmark.RUN_NODE_NAME)))
{
                styleNode = this.getStyleNode(lastRunNode);
                if (styleNode != null) {
                    run.getCTR().getDomNode().insertBefore(
                            styleNode.cloneNode(true),
run.getCTR().getDomNode().getFirstChild());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried using getStyleNode method but getting null in return value . I am passing bookmark.getDomNode() as parameter value. Please suggest me the correct implementation.